# Accessing RabbitMQ from different clusters/machines

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-platform

I have a RabbitMQ instance deployed on a google cloud engine. I also have a hadoop instance deployed on a different google cloud engine but still in the same application. I am trying to connect to the RabbitMQ queue instance from the hadoop clusters but with no success.

I have a java application that should push items on the RabbitMQ queue and then receive them in the same application. The following is the connection java code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("130.211.112.37:5672");
        try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i get the following result:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 130.211.112.37:5672
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:615)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:639)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.io.impl.SparkStreamProcessorObserver.<clinit>(SparkStreamProcessorObserver.java:157)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.evaluation.Main.main(Main.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried opening port 5672 on google cloud firewall. Does anyone has some pointers to the solution please?

Best 
Jeremy

Comment: Try using:
factory.setHost(hostName);
factory.setPort(portNumber);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wrote to the comment:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        //factory.setHost("130.211.112.37:5672"); <----- sethost accepts only the host! 
         factory.setHost("130.211.112.37"); 
         factory.setPort(5672); 
        try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

By default the port is `5672`,  so `setPort` it is not necessary.
You have to use `setPort` only if you change the default port.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html you need to call `setHost` and `setPort` to  create a connection. In your app you are passing the host and port together on the same line.